# Can't find DLL entry point MessageBoxIndirectW in user32 when opening Excel Solver

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ms-office

I have MS Office 365 on my work computer and keep on getting this error.

[image]

I have tried the solutions here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2010/run-time-error-453-cant-find-dll-entry-point-solv/c188ea01-7eda-4b46-b43b-64695fc3ce8f
but they don't really work since I'm on Office 365, so there's not a separate MS Excel install, it's just a MS Office install.  I've tried repairing, both quick and full, and restarting my computer.

All I am trying to do is to open solver.  Any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Office 365. My IT department installed an update and it fixed the problem.  Apparently, I was only getting updates every 6 months versus monthly updates.